# Transitions for dynamic placeholders in input boxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input box to ask questions. The placeholder has a sample question. I want to change the placeholder every 10 seconds and there should be a transition when the placeholder value changes. I can change the placeholder values. Any ideas how to animate it?

Here's a basic sample of the code

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.placeholderTexts = [
        "what day is today?",
        "how's the weather today?",
        "what's trending today?"
      ]
    this.state = {
      currentText : this.placeholderTexts[0],
      idx : 1
    }
    this.changePlaceholders = this.changePlaceholders.bind(this);
    this.changePlaceholders();

  }

  changePlaceholders(){
    setInterval(function(){
        this.setState({currentText : this.placeholderTexts[this.state.idx]});
      this.setState({idx : (this.state.idx+1)%3});
    }.bind(this),1000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input id="" placeholder={this.state.currentText}></input>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The placeholders should slide up when they change. I want to now where to include the sliding transition.